# Google Drive V3 Resumable Download

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I use this code to download a file from Google Drive using Google Drive api V3:

```
    Function gDownload() As Boolean

            Dim fileID As String = "0B-W1aRTTOB1QM3hPd0dOUFVObHM"
            Dim stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()        
            Dim r = service.Files.Get(fileID)
            Dim m = r.MediaDownloader
            m.ChunkSize = 256 * 1024
            AddHandler m.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Download_ProgressChanged    
    mStart:    
            r.Download(stream)    
            Return True ' or False if download failed

    End Function

   Private Sub Download_ProgressChanged(s As IDownloadProgress)
            Console.WriteLine(s.Status.ToString & "   " & s.BytesDownloaded)
   End Sub
```

This works fine with stable connection but if I lose connection it stops and waits forever even if I reconnect again.

I don't have this problem with update (upload) function in this code:

```
Function gUpload() As Boolean

        Dim fileID As String = "0B-W1aRTTOB1QM3hPd0dOUFVObHM"
        Dim stream As New System.IO.FileStream("D:\gtest\Test.mp4", System.IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim fBody As File = New File With {.Name = "Test.mp4"}

        Dim r = service.Files.Update(fBody, fileID, stream, "application/octet-stream")
        r.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize
        AddHandler r.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Upload_ProgressChanged

  mStart:
        r.Resume()
        If r.GetProgress.Status = 3 Then ' UploadStatus.Completed
            Return True
        Else
            If MessageBox.Show("Failed. do you want to resume?", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                GoTo mStart
            End If
        End If
        Return False
End Function    

Private Sub Upload_ProgressChanged(s As IUploadProgress)
    Console.WriteLine(s.Status.ToString & "   " & s.BytesSent)
End Sub
```

This works exactly as I want, if I lose connection for some time (15~30s) it gives a message that upload is failed and gives a user a choice to resume or exit. everything work perfectly.

So my question is: how to make the download function works like the upload function or at least make it don't wait forever and gives a fail message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I resolved temporarily with a "while"

```
    Request.DownloadAsync(Stream)

    Dim bytes_downloaded As Long = 0
    Dim not_downloaded As Integer = 0
    Dim progress As Integer = Stream.Length
    Do While progress < file_size
        progress = Stream.Length

        If progress = bytes_downloaded Then
            not_downloaded += 1
            If not_downloaded >= 900 Then '90 seconds
                ' msg download falhou
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            not_downloaded = 0
        End If
        bytes_downloaded = progress
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop
```

Comment: Thank you, I did very similar thing as a workaround of this problem, but I'm sure Google Drive has a better way and we couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your Download_ProgressChanged procedure like tihs:

```
Private Sub Download_ProgressChanged(s As IDownloadProgress)
  Select Case s.Status
    Case DownloadStatus.Downloading
        If True Then
            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded)
            Exit Select
        End If
    Case DownloadStatus.Completed
        If True Then
            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.")
            Exit Select
        End If
    Case DownloadStatus.Failed
        If True Then
            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.")
            Exit Select
        End If
  End Select
End Sub
```

Link is here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads.

You can use partial download bu you have to calculate start and end bytes.

Comment: Thank you, but `s.Status` is always 'DownloadStatus.Downloading` and never become `Failed` or `Completed`.